# Django ManyToMany Through Relationship

Tags: python, django, database-design, django-models, django-orm

I have a following criteria

where I have User Model, which itself extended was from Django user model.

```
Class User
   name = models.CharField()
   ...
```

A user can become a seller when he is approved by the admin. Seller model goes like this.

```
Class Seller
    location = models.CharField()
    INDIVIDUAL = '1'
    COMPANY = '2'
    ACCOUNT_CHOICES = (
        (INDIVIDUAL, 'individual'), 
        (COMPANY, 'company'),
    )

    account_type_name = models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=ACCOUNT_CHOICES, default=INDIVIDUAL)
```

And Seller can belong to any of the second or third level categories

```
Class Level1Category
    name = models.CharField()

Class Level2Category
    name = models.CharField()
    level1 = models.ForeignKey(Level1Category)

Class Level3Category
    name = models.CharField()
    level2 = models.ForeignKey(Level2Category)
```

When a user apply for seller account he has to select any one of the level 2 or level 3 category. Which would be the efficient model architecture for this. How can I link the category model with the seller and also link these two models with the user.

**EDIT**

My User Model is already a extended version of Django User Model. I'm doing that because I have two different type of profiles, one is seller and the other is buyer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try by extending Django's User model ([see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model))

Your seller would extend from your User model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    ....

class Seller(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   location = models.CharField()
   ...
```

You could create a ManyToMany relationship for your categories ([see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships)):

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

Or one thing that come to mind, you maybe could extend what you have done for your account_type_name:

```
LEVEL_CATEGORY = (
    (1, 'Level 1'), 
    (2, 'Level 2'),
    (3, 'Level 2'),
)

level_category = models.CharField(choices=LEVEL_CATEGORY, default=1)
```

But I am not sure if this is really what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks Hendrick. My user model is already extened fom Django User Model. There are two types of profile, seller and buyer which uses User model which itself extended from Django user model.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just basic user field such as; name, email etc, you can extend Django's User model as @HendrikF suggest then;

```
class Seller(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   location = models.CharField()
   ...
```

if you need customize User model I do suggest you Django AbstractUser for example;

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    consumer = models.ForeignKey('Consumer', null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```